# JavaFX Changing Scene Instead of Stage

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm currently making a program and using JavaFX as the main GUI setting. Currently I'm opening and closing each stage as I go into each different method.

This is a little bit annoying as to the user there are a lot of screens opening and closing when they go through the program.

My question is this, is there a way to instead of opening a stage every time I can move into a different part of my program, I could switch between scenes instead? Would switching between scenes be the correct implementation in this scenario? Would I need to pass a stage between methods?

As you can probably tell I'm just getting started with JavaFX so would appreciate a bit of a lesson.

EDIT: I have decided to update my application using JavaFXML, However I am having difficulties passing a scene into my controller. Here is my Controller;

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    @FXML
    public Stage primaryStage;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane rootLayout;

    @FXML
    private JobInterface jInterface;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage = new Stage();
        setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
        initRootLayout();
    }

    @FXML
    public void initRootLayout(){
        try {
            primaryStage = getPrimaryStage();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("MainInterface.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();        
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);    
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
         } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    @FXML
    private void setJobLayout(){
        primaryStage = getPrimaryStage();
        jInterface = new JobInterface();
        jInterface.initJobLayout();
        primaryStage.setScene(jInterface.getScene());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }
}
```

Here is a method that is changing the scene using a different FXML file and attempting to pass the scene back to the controller;

```
public class JobInterface {

    private AnchorPane rootLayout;
    private Scene scene;

    public void initJobLayout(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("JobInterface.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            setScene(scene);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Scene getScene() {
        return scene;
    }

    public void setScene(Scene scene) {
        this.scene = scene;
    }   
}
```

The issue I'm having now is a NullPointerException on this line in the main app;

```
primaryStage.setScene(jInterface.getScene());
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Yes you can keep the primary stage that the JavaFX provides at init and change its scene for different UI "pages". Or since scene has the only one root node layout, you can even use the same scene and change the root node of it on different "pages". In both cases don't forget to invoke primaryStage.sizeToScene() after navigating to the new "page".

Comment: So would I just need to pass the stage through each method? Would that work correctly? Example: uInterface.UserUI(connection, primaryStage);

Comment: There are different approaches. Some guys keep the primary stage as public static and access it directly. Some get the scene by, (in controller class) anynode.getScene(), or to stage by anynode.getScene().getWindow().

Comment: @jbanks Yes, that would work correctly. Or you can define a `getScene()` method in your `UserInterface` class, returning the `Scene` it creates, and then do `primaryStage.setScene(uInterface.getScene())` in the login button handler. There are many ways...

Comment: @James_D, I've edited the above question to modify it for an FXML problem I've come across

Answer (score 2):

Non-Animated

For changing scene without Animation tutorials:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setScene%28javafx.scene.Scene%29
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html#getChildren%28%29

Animated

For changing scene with Animation tutorials:
https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1
https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx